# Getting the average of the array using ES6?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have been trying to get the average of rankings through the function i have created, everything works great if i pass an array through the getAverage() function but not when i want to pass it from the list array?

```
const list = [{
  name: "Ben",
  ranking: 3
}, {
  name: "Harry",
  ranking: 1
}, {
  name: "Kim",
  ranking: 2
}, {
  name: "John",
  ranking: 5
}, {
  name: "Liz",
  ranking: 4
}];

//Average of ranking
const getAverage = (arr) => {
  const reducer = (total, currentValue) => total + currentValue;
  const sum = arr.reduce(reducer);
  return sum / arr.length;
}
getAverage();
```

Comment: You never pass anything to the function, so `arr` would be `undefined`.

Comment: Why would you not want to pass the data to the function you are calling. If you don’t pass anything the code will do nothing. So the correct code should be `getAverage(list)`

Comment: @ParthManaktala getAverage(list); returns NaN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is close. Remember, you're iterating over an array of objects, not an array of values.

```
const getAverage = (arr) => {
  const reducer = (total, currentObj) => total + currentObj.ranking;
  const sum = arr.reduce(reducer, 0);
  return sum / arr.length;
}
// use: 
// console.log(getAverage(list));
```

**EDIT**
Also, you need to initialize the reducer's starting value to zero, otherwise it'll be adding the numbers to undefined, resulting in NaN.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Great help! I totally forgot to initialise the reducers starting value.

Answer (score -2):

Why have you split the reducer function from the actual reduce? Also, there is no initial value for the .reduce, so I would suggest:-

`const sum = arr.reduce((total,current) => total += current.ranking,0)`

```
const getAverage = (arr) => {
  return arr.reduce((total,current) => total += current.ranking,0) / arr.length
}

// and don't forget to pass the actual array to the function...

getAverage(arr)
```

Comment: Why the `+=` operator? You just did same thing in another answer. Really only need `+`...in other words return the sum of the two values. Beyond that you are adding object to number

Comment: "*Why have you split the reducer function from the actual reduce?*" that is not an issue. "*Also, there is no initial value for the .reduce,*" this is a potential problem but not what OP is asking about. This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Yep, you could probably get away with just the `+`, but it kind of make sense that you want to total to the whatever it is plus the current value.

Comment: @user3094755 doesn't make a difference - that value is returned immediately, anyway - it's not like the assignment to `total` would ever be used.

Comment: Try running this...will see that it fails using OP's input